# importError tkinter when importing matplotlib

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, pip

I am unable to import matplotlib on [this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB) deep learning AMI from aws marketplace

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

And I get this error

> ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'

What I've tried (and the errors returned):

```
pip install tkinter
> No matching distribution found for TKinter

sudo yum install tkinter
> No package tkinter available.
> Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo yum install python-tkinter`?

Comment: yes, same error as ```sudo yum install tkinter```

Comment: Are you running python2 or python3?

Comment: I am using python2

Comment: you can't install tkinter with pip, FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find location of matplotlibrc file

`import matplotlib
 matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`

> u'/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc'

Then go to this file and change the current configuration of backend to
`backend : agg`

This does not solve the problem of import Tkinter, but it does allow the import of pyplot

Answer (score 0):

I personnally had this kind of troubles with tkinter, before to realize it requires a 't' in python3 and a 'T' in python2. so when I need compatibility my codes contain:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0]>2:
    # for Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
else:
    # for Python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
```

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
```

Had the same problem after updating to new matplotlib 2.x on python 3.5.x

Comment: yeah, that's basically what I did. Except instead I just set this in the matplotlibrc file. Checkout my answer

Comment: I thought this might be more convenient than to alter a file. Also it is a solution that only changes the backend within that specific script, is it not? As far as I understand your solution, it would change the backend globally for all scripts until you change the matplotlib file again.

Comment: yeah, if the goal was to only alter the backend for this script your answer would be best. However, I found my answer worked best for me because I was running into this error  in multiple scripts in a project.